# Change an ID value of a form element with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a requirement to change the id of a form element dynamically. For example, the elements are in a sequence in form like id1, id2, id3 and id4 (the number of elements is not fixed to 4 and can be more than that). I need to add an element after id1 as id2. when this happens, the id2 which already in the form should change as id3 and id3 should change as id4 and so on. I thought of putting it in a recursive function with javascript but didn't get any idea as of now....Please help.

Comment: Doesn't sound like you should be using IDs for this, maybe a `data-order` attribute. Could you post your need for the IDs to be in order?

Comment: Im working with dynamic add of repeating groups (fieldsets) with javascript. I will have to change the fieldset id's which Im able to to if the add is in a sequence but fails if the add process is not in a sequence (if the user adds an element in the second position first and then adds an element in first position.

Comment: Is using jQuery an option or does this need plain JavaScript?

Answer (score 3):

With jquery you can do this:
You have some html tags with class "listItem" and an id.

```
<div id="1" class="listItem">something </div>
<div id="2" class="listItem">something </div>
<div id="3" class="listItem">something </div>
```

Then the script

```
var i = 2;
$(".listItem").each(function() {
     $(this).attr("id", i++);
});
```

This should change the content to

```
<div id="2" class="listItem">something </div>
<div id="3" class="listItem">something </div>
<div id="4" class="listItem">something </div>
```

This will iterate through all tags that have class "listItem" and will change the id.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi...Thanks for the response. I'm working with javascript and also this will change the id of a particular element and not as a recursive one right..?

Comment: Correct. What you could do is give the elements a class so you can iterate over them and change them all. I will edit my answer and show you how you can do it.

Comment: When im home in 10mins because its hard on the phone :p

Comment: There you go, that is the cleanest way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your html was like this:

```
<div id="id1" class="list"></div>
<div id="id2" class="list"></div>
<div id="id3" class="list"></div>
```

You can create a function that inserts a new element in the middle and updates the ids of all the following elements in two steps as follows:

```
function(insertAfterId) {
  jQuery('#' + insertAfterId).insert('<div id="temp" class="list"></div>');
  var count = 1;
  jQuery('.list').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).attr("id", "id" + count);
    count++;
  });
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Whats the down vote about? The answer above by jonathan.cruz was created **after** I had already posted my answer!